# Why can't I disable desktop composition when running OBS?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Recording me playing FTL using OBS v0.655b 64bit Portable significantly decreased FTL's framerate.

Temporary change to *Windows Basic* theme fixed this issue, so I wanted Windows to switch to lighter theme every time I run OBS. However, the checkbox doing this is impossible to enable. I never seen something like this. **Why does this happen? How can I workaround this?**

[image: Disabled settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OBS offers a separate function that does this:

Go to *Settings* -> *Video* -> *"Disable Aero on startup"* (or similar).
From now on OBS attempts to disable the Aero service and switches to a lighter theme whenever it is launched.